# Is there a group that the Trump administration has (re)designated for TPS?

Tags: united-states, refugees, complementary-protection

In [a story from last year](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2018/jan/31/syria-tps-extended-trump-administration):

> The Trump administration will let 6,900 Syrians who had been allowed to live and work in the US because of dangerous conditions in their home country remain in the US for at least the next 18 months.
>
> **For the first time since the designation was made in March 2012, however, the US government did not re-designate it, which would allow more people to qualify for the protection.**
>
> TPS is different from the refugee and asylum programs because it is meant for people who have already entered the US, usually to visit family, study or work. **Syrians who entered the US after 1 August 2016 do not qualify for TPS, but they could have if it had been re-designated.**

So, is there any other group that the Trump administration has [re]designated for TPS? (And to repeat, I'm not talking about merely extending the stay of those already in the US.)

---

Since someone asked for a [summary of TPS](https://www.rescue.org/article/behind-headlines-temporary-protected-status):

> To be eligible for TPS, nationals must prove continuous residence in the U.S. from the date the status was granted by the Department of Homeland Security (DHS). Individuals who arrive in the U.S. after the date in question are not eligible for TPS. Foreign nationals who qualify for this lifesaving immigration program can live and work in the U.S. legally for the duration of the status, typically 18 months. TPS holders do not currently have a pathway to lawful permanent status.
>
> DHS is required to extend or terminate TPS country designations 60 days before the status expires. In the event TPS is extended, DHS will also determine whether or not to re-designate it, so that individuals who arrived after the prior designation date may also be eligible to apply for the status. When TPS is extended for a country, nationals with TPS must re-register for the status.
>
> TPS has historically been extended and re-designated in accordance with the law under both Republican and Democratic administrations alike — until now. [...]
>
> Syria, Yemen, Somalia and South Sudan have had TPS extended for 18 months but not re-designated under this administration, meaning that foreign nationals arriving to the U.S. after the designation date are not eligible for the status.
>
> The next decisions will be in 2019 for South Sudan and Syria and 2020 for Yemen and Somalia.

So the answer appears to be no (re)designations whatsoever under Trump, but that page is from six months ago.

Comment: It would help the question if you explained what TPS is and/or what it does.

Comment: @Karlomanio: I've added a summary, although that could have been part of an answer as well.

Comment: How would a Syrian refugee even arrive to the country without getting a refugee visa? Unlike Europe the US is lucky enough to be separated by a vast ocean from the war zone.

Comment: @JonathanReez: agreed, but TPS was also granted to some Latin American countries; in fact that's the majority of current TPS holders. I don't know if those got in illegally or not before being granted TPS, but illegal entry is a less remote possibility for them.